# Perform file download for multiple dates using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to download this website content (the web link shown on picture number 1 (www.idx.co.id/en-us/market-data/trading-summary/stock-summary/)

[image]

using button as shown below, but this time I need to automate the download processes for multiple dates (the website interface could be seen from picture number 2, there is a date selector to choose the date) So it can create multiple files from different dates. Are there anyone can help me to perform this activity? Currently I'm working with python 3, pandas dataframe.

[image]

Comment: I would check out [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). You can write some code to navigate through the side and pull data from it dynamically.